# NSDateFormatter format string for RFC 3339 date string without milliseconds

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdateformatter, date-parsing

I am having an issue trying to parse an Atom RFC 3339 date coming from a feed. Is is coming in is form: `@"2014-07-21T11:36:05-05:00"` and the following formats fail to parse it... any help?

```
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"]; 

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZZZ"]; 

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"]; 

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.ZZZZ"];
```

Comment: Use a format that actually matches your string. Everything is right up to and include the `ss` but then you get it wrong for the timezone. Your first option is closest but you need five `Z`s for a timezone in that format.

Comment: BTW - get rid of all of the ticks except around the "T".

Comment: see comment below please

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: Actually pasting the code in a fresh project seems to work. The issue is somewhere else it seems... thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a `.` in the last format??  I don't see one in your source string.

Comment: The issue is resolved, but to answer the question, all those formats are chained in the code because different RSS feeds use them. If one fails, the next one tries. I was just showing all the formats I was using at the moment of the bug. Clearly I am not fully familiar with NSDateFormatter and don't always know if a character is special or literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format you need is

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

The five `Z` pattern is a recent-ish addition to the formatting library that handles exactly this time zone format.

(Despite [Apple's Technical Q&A 1480 on this topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html) (and the identical code in the date formatting guide), the only item in the format string that *needs* to be escaped with apostrophes is the `T` -- [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns), which governs the format strings, says that only ASCII letters, a-z and A-Z, are reserved. It also says, however, that punctuation *may* be used in the future, so you *can* quote the colons and hyphens if you like.)